# $Request variable becomes null on live server but it has a value in production(localhost)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem that I can't get my head around so I need your help.

I have a function in my controller that accepts a form with a checkbox:

```
if (isset($request->check0)) {
        $calendar2 = Calendar::create([
                'user_id' => $userid,
                'event_id' => $request->event0
    ]);
```

$request->event0 is registered as an integer when im in development but when I go live with the same code this value becomes null.

Completely stumped. Any help would be really appreciated.

Kind Regards

**EDIT** Issue solved. This was one checkbox of 4 on the form and there was a php loop in the view that looked like this:

```
<?php $x = 0;?>
                    @foreach($classes as $class)
                    <h4>{{$class->title}}</h4> 
                    <input id="check<? echo $x; ?>" name="check<? echo $x; ?>" type="checkbox" checked />
                    <input id="event<? echo $x; ?>" name="event<? echo $x; ?>" type="hidden" value="{{$class->id}}">
                    <? $x++;?>
                    @endforeach
```

Making sure I used full  tags solved the problem:

```
<?php $x = 0;?>
                    @foreach($classes as $class)
                    <h4>{{$class->title}}</h4> 
                    <input id="check<?php echo $x; ?>" name="check<?php echo $x; ?>" type="checkbox" checked />
                    <input id="event<?php echo $x; ?>" name="event<?php echo $x; ?>" type="hidden" value="{{$class->id}}">
                    <?php $x++;?>
                    @endforeach
```

Comment: Correction: Live server is production, localhost is development

Comment: Fixed - Thanks friend

Comment: Can you try using using the get method? ```$request->get('event0')```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, try `$request->get('event0')`. Not that this the solution but just trying something different. Perhaps the keyword event is doing something else?

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference unfortunately

Comment: Can you `dd($request)` and see what's contained in there ? on your production (live) server.

Comment: It's working guys. dd($request), gave me a clearer picture what was going on. I had PHP tags like this <? ?> in the view and they needed to be <?php ?>. I will post full write up in my main post. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on blade

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check0' value=1>
<input type='hidden' name='check0' value=0>
```